# Обрезка изображения по заданной пользователем области

Tags: jquery, изображения, php

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с проблемой crop'а изображений. Использовал [данный crop](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/tree/master/examples/crop-avatar).
Все хорошо, область для обрезки изображения произвольная в jquery установлена, но в php файле указывается фиксированный размер:

```
$dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor(220, 220);
            $result = imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $data -> x, $data -> y, 220, 220, $data -> width, $data -> height);
```

А нужно, чтобы обрезало именно по той области, что задается пользователем. Может, кто уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой?